# Deploy Visual C++ 2005 express edition in silent mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I want to install visual c++ 2005 express edition on window 10 in silent mode therefore i need to use unattend file
and when itry to create it with this line in cmd:

```
[path]/setup.exe /createunattend [path]/vs2005.ini
```

i get this message: CreateUnattend and / UnattendFile are not supported for this product.

Any idea to solve it!

Comment: As far as I'm concerned,  Visual C++ 2005 express edition is an old edition, and is [no longer supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Visual%20C%2B%2B%202005) by Microsoft. So maybe there are some limitations on Windows 10 and Visual C++ 2005 express. Microsoft recommends customers upgrade to the latest Visual Studio.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/astebner/how-to-silently-install-visual-studio-2005-express-editions  I think i found the solution here but i did not understand what should to do, maybe you can confirm it!

Best regards

Comment: The learn.microsoft.com solution shows command lines for each component of Visual Studio 2005 Express Editions.

Also, note that you should enable Microsoft Update on your clients to ensure SP1 and related updates get downloaded and installed.  Beware that in Windows 10 you may need to do repair installs after each Feature Update as it has a tendency to corrupt certain components of the product (this applies to all Visual Studio 2005 products, not just Express).